# Mercurial and gwsmhg

Tags: user-interface, mercurial

Has anybody use gwsmhg GUI tool for Mercurial? Any luck running it on Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Why not ask such questions on the [Mercurial mailing lists](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/MailingLists)? I would expect that to be a much better forum for such questions.

I searched, and found some [previous discussion on gwsmhg](http://mercurial.markmail.org/search/gwsmhg). There it is compared to [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home) and the message is that it might be better for managing [mq patches](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/MqExtension). (But I have not tried gwsmhg.)